# How to determine entry point of java with long classpath

Tags: java

Hi I am not a java programmer but am trying to debug someone else's code.

I have windows bat file with java.exe -classpath followed by a very lengthy list. How do I find which java program is the entry point -- or in other words what the heck actually executes?

As requested here is the first part of the command

```
C:\DSUpload\java\bin\java.exe -classpath C:\DSUpload\.adf;C:\DSUpload\classes;C:\DSUpload\wlserver_10.3\server\lib\weblogic.jar;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The java class file will probably be the last part of the command, if not, then it will be the only part of the command that is not preceded by a flag/option.

Example:

```
java -cp foo;bar;baz JavaClass
```

Here, "JavaClass" is the class being run, as it is below:

```
java -cp foo;bar;baz JavaClass -d someDir
```

The entry point of a java program is always its "main" method, which has the following signature (the parameter name can vary):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Comment: Hey thanks very much. I hadn't noticed a space after the very long list of paths.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify a class name to execute, then you must specify a -jar which will contain a Manifest that that a main-class attribute (main class which will be the entry point).